# Join multiple items in a form to one text-file

Tags: php, forms

This question might be very simple, but I'm having problems figuring out how to make it work. I've made some research but couldn't work a solution. I'm by no means a PHP expert, I just know the basics to read a code and modify some minor things if needed. In fact, this might be my first script from zero.

I play a football management game with a database editor. In order to keep it updated and save myself some time I'm making an script to "automate" some of the things I do manually player by player, which takes me a lot of time. As the database allows to export and import clubs, I can do all the work on a php script. For example, I set the name, age, position, nationality, skills, etc, of a player in the script and I get it formatted to be imported to the game.

The script works as I want for one player. I have a html form, I fill the data, then the script does it works and get me the .txt output with a format that my game can read.

Now what I need is to have more forms like the first one, fill all of them (every form is a player) at the same time and get the .txt with the format I need to import it.

I've tried with arrays, but for some reason I'm not finding the solution to make it work. I've also read that an object-oriented approach might be the solution, but after some research, that just exceeds my knowledge.

I know it might be plain simple, but I don't know how to solve it. I'll post here the codes for one player (no arrays, just the bare form) in the hope that someone might help me. As a final note, I'm sure most of the code can be optimised or corrected. It's just for personal use and will run in my own localhost, so I'm not worried right now for it until I have it working in the way I want.

To give you an example, the txt output for a player is something like this

```
%INDEX%PLAYER
Name
Last Name
Date of Birth
A
lot
of
data
%INDEXEND%PLAYER
```

I want that after the first player, the second player gets formatted with it's own data using the same script and get this:

```
%INDEX%PLAYER
    Name
    Last Name
    Date of Birth
    A
    lot
    of
    data
    %INDEXEND%PLAYER
%INDEX%PLAYER
    Second
    Player
    Date of Birth
    A
    lot
    of
    data
    %INDEXEND%PLAYER
```

Thanks to everyone, sorry for the long post and I hope I've made myself clear.

Codes - form.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="process-form-data.php">
<table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="3">
  <tr>
    <td><label>Nombre: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" /></td>
    <td><label>Apellido: </label>
      <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" /></td>
    <td><label>Pseudonimo: </label>
      <input type="text" name="pseudom" id="pseudom" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fecha Nac: <select name='dia' >
    <option value='1' selected title='1'>1</option>
    <option title='2' value='2'>2</option>
    <option title='3' value='3'>3</option>
    <option title='4' value='4'>4</option>
    <option title='5' value='5'>5</option>
    <option title='6' value='6'>6</option>
    <option title='7' value='7'>7</option>
    <option title='8' value='8'>8</option>
    <option title='9' value='9'>9</option>
    <option title='10' value='10'>10</option>
    <option title='11' value='11'>11</option>
    <option title='12' value='12'>12</option>
    <option title='13' value='13'>13</option>
    <option title='14' value='14'>14</option>
    <option title='15' value='15'>15</option>
    <option title='16' value='16'>16</option>
    <option title='17' value='17'>17</option>
    <option title='18' value='18'>18</option>
    <option title='19' value='19'>19</option>
    <option title='20' value='20'>20</option>
    <option title='21' value='21'>21</option>
    <option title='22' value='22'>22</option>
    <option title='23' value='23'>23</option>
    <option title='24' value='24'>24</option>
    <option title='25' value='25'>25</option>
    <option title='26' value='26'>26</option>
    <option title='27' value='27'>27</option>
    <option title='28' value='28'>28</option>
    <option title='29' value='29'>29</option>
    <option title='30' value='30'>30</option>
    <option title='31' value='31'>31</option>
</select>
<select name='mes' >
    <option value='1' selected title='1'>1</option>
    <option title='2' value='2'>2</option>
    <option title='3' value='3'>3</option>
    <option title='4' value='4'>4</option>
    <option title='5' value='5'>5</option>
    <option title='6' value='6'>6</option>
    <option title='7' value='7'>7</option>
    <option title='8' value='8'>8</option>
    <option title='9' value='9'>9</option>
    <option title='10' value='10'>10</option>
    <option title='11' value='11'>11</option>
    <option title='12' value='12'>12</option>
</select>
<input name="year" type="text" id="year" size="4" />
</td>
    <td>Nac: <select name='nac' >
    // Dropdown Options</td></select>
    <td>Talento: 
      <select name='talento' >
    <option title='Normal' value='0'>Normal</option>
    <option title='Medio' value='1'>Medio</option>
    <option title='Grande' value='2'>Grande</option>
    <option title='Espectacular' value='3'>Espectacular</option>
    <option title='Enorme' value='5'>Enorme</option>
</select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Posicion:  <select name='position' >
    // Dropdown Options
</select></td>
    <td>Educacion Táctica: <select name='edtat' >
        <option value='0'  title='0'>0</option>
    // Dropdown Options </select> </td>
    <td>Altura: <input name="altura" type="text" id="altura" size="4" /> Peso: <input name="peso" type="text" id="peso" size="4" /> Tipo Cara: <select name='tipocara' >
    <option title='Africano' value='1'>Africano</option>
    <option title='Arabe' value='2'>Arabe</option>
    <option title='Caucasico' value='4'>Caucasico</option>
    <option title='Europa Este' value='5'>Europa Este</option>
    <option title='Asiatico' value='3'>Asiatico</option>
    <option title='Latino' value='6'>Latino</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Tecnico: </label><input type="text" name="niveltec" id="niveltec" size="4" />
                 <label>Mental: </label><input type="text" name="nivelmen" id="nivelmen" size="4" />
                  <label>Fisico: </label><input type="text" name="nivelfis" id="nivelfis" size="4" />
                   <label>Faltas: </label><input type="text" name="nivelfaltas" id="nivelfaltas" size="4" /></td>
                   <td>Exp Local: <select name='exploc' >
        <option value='0'  title='0'>0</option>
    <option value='1' title='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2' selected title='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3' title='3'>3</option>
    <option title='4' value='4'>4</option>
    <option title='5' value='5'>5</option>
</select>Exp Int: <select name='expint' >
        <option value='0'  title='0'>0</option>
    <option value='1' title='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2' selected title='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3' title='3'>3</option>
    <option title='4' value='4'>4</option>
    <option title='5' value='5'>5</option>
</select></td>
<td><p><label>Imagen: </label><input type="text" name="imagen" id="imagen" /></p></td></tr>

</table>
<p><input type="submit" name="s1" id="s1" value="Submit" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Processor

```
<?php
include 'positions.php';
include 'tipocara.php';

//Vamos a obtener los datos
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
$dia = $_POST['dia'];
$mes = $_POST['mes'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$nac = $_POST['nac'];
$nac2 = $_POST['nac2'];
$talento = $_POST['talento'];
$edtat = $_POST['edtat'];
$dorsal = $_POST['dorsal'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$peso = $_POST['peso'];
$exploc = $_POST['exploc'];
$expint = $_POST['expint'];

if (isset($_POST['pseudom'])) {
    $pseudo = $_POST['pseudom'] . "\r\n";
} else {
    $pseudo = "\r\n";
}

if ($_POST['vasco'] == '1') {
    $plr = 6;
} else {
    $plr = 4;
}

//Un jugador tiene el 10% de chance de tener algun atributo heroíco
$heroerand = rand(1,100);

if ($heroerand < 10) {
$heroevalue = rand(1,9);
    $heroe = $heroevalue;
} else {
    $heroe = 0;
}


$imagen = $_POST['imagen'];

//copiar imagen y cambiarle nombre
//$prueba = substr($name, 0, 2);
//$prueba2 = $prueba . $email . ".png";



//Vamos a armar el jugador

// $playercode = Here is the php code to format the player, but as it's a line per line work to not make a long post

$fp = fopen("formdata.txt", "a");
$savestring = $playercode;
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);

//copy($imagen,$prueba2);
echo "<h1>You data has been saved in a text file!</h1>";


?>
```

Comment: That sounds fun :) I like playing football management games myself. But it is a bit of work. And judging from your code, I have no clue about how to get the data of all the players. But php is actually an object oriented proggramming language. What you need to do is create a **Players Class** and do what you want to do inside that class, like assigning variables and running functions. And then run a `foreach` loop to put all the players into a table. And iterate through the table. As i said, i can't see the whole picture, so it is hard to assume, at least for me :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting :) The data is putted manually by me in a form. That is the first file. Then the data gets processed in the other file (there are two other files involved which runs some functions based on some dropdowns of the form, but that's not the issue) and gets printed in a text file. I'm running the form in a very basic way: the form data is passed as post variables, then I get them on the processor. No arrays, no objects. That's my issue, I don't know how to reiterate this process in the same form. If you need any more data I can give it to see if there's a solution.

Comment: To be a little more clear, imagine if I copy the form on the first file and paste it below, so I'll have two forms for two players, that's how I'll get the data. But my issue is that I can't make it work for more players, only for one.

Comment: How many forms are we talking about? 2,3,4 or more? Because having multiple forms by copy/paste is not an elegant way of handling things. And forget about **php** or any coding, It is still unclear to me how you are going to operate two or more forms at the same time. If you say you can, then you should use a table with header information `<th>` like **Nombre Apellido Pseudonimo Fecha Nac Nac Talento....** And only inputs should remain on `<td>` not the labels. And with each player in one row you can edit the players, and send the data to process with **ajax**. Sorry if this sounds complicated